# Cannot get presence informations even thought developer portal switches are enabled discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fetch

I have my code here :

```js
// ...
    run: (client,message,args) =>{
        let member = message.member
        console.log(member.presence) // null
        if(!member.presence) return message.say(`${n} - I cannot access **${member.nickname || member.user.tag}**'s presence.`)
        if(!member.presence.activities[0]) return message.reply(`${n} - No activity detected from \`${member.user.tag} !\``)
        message.reply('Informations logged on the console.')
        console.log(member.presence)
    }
```

I keep having my bot sending this :

[image: No activity detected]

After having checked if other people got the same issue I only saw people who didn't activated the following check boxes :

[image: The switches]

The thing is I already did and no matter how many times I rerun my bot, `member.presence` keeps being null and I can't understand why.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I've already fixed my problem 1 hour ago but thanks

Comment: I've seen that. The comment above is just an automated message as I voted to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've been checking around a little more and I found out it's just because I didn't put [`GUILD_PRESENCES`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents) in my intents, silly me.

I just had to change this

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents : [
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MEMBERS",
    "GUILD_MESSAGES"
  ]
})
```

to this :

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents : [
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MEMBERS",
    "GUILD_MESSAGES",
    "GUILD_PRESENCES"
  ]
})
```

And restarting my bot fixed it all!